# Autocmds for particular filetypes

Tags: vimrc

I'm trying to understand using the `autocmd` to modify properties for certain files. Here is a basic example I have in my `vimrc`:

```
syntax on
autocmd BufRead *.py syntax off
```

However, when I then open up a new python file, **all** files in that window (whether python or not) have their syntax highlighting removed. For example:

[image]

Why does this occur, and what would be the proper way to change something for only the filetype I'm referencing and not other windows/splits?

Note: the same thing also happens with:

```
autocmd FileType python syntax off
```

From [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/12.html#filetype-events):

> One of the most useful events is the `FileType` event. This event is fired whenever Vim sets a buffer's `filetype`.

But if the user has to manually set the `ft` everytime a file is opened, it seems quite useless (if I'm understanding things correctly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `:syntax` command is global. Probably you're looking for the "local to buffer" setting `'syntax'` (abbreviation: `'syn'`). To disable for current file:

```
set syn=OFF
```

per `:h 'syn'` though `set syn=` and `set syn&` seem to work, too.

You can use this with a filetype auto command like so:

```
autocmd FileType python set syn=OFF
```

Each time you open a Python file it should be without syntax highlighting.

(I wouldn't be surprised if there were other ways to accomplish this but I verified the above works.)