# When does filetype run?

Tags: filetype

I have the following autocmd:

```
:autocmd FileType python syntax off
```

Yet when I open a python file it does nothing. I literally have to run `:set ft=python` for this to trigger. Does the `FileType python` not run when reading a buffer? What is the usual way to apply changes at the file-specific level?

Comment: Sure this isn't a duplicate of [Autocmds for particular filetypes](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/25854)  (which I answered)?

Comment: Er, how are you sure the file is a python file (file suffix, i assume)? Are you using `:filetype on` (or one of its variants that include ftplugins or indent scripts)? Ftplugins are generally a better way to handle this. But filetype event is triggered when filetype is set. The command i gave turns on the detection mechanism which causes filetypes to be set when editing files (thereby triggering the event...)

Comment: @BLayer not really -- the other is a great answer (which I've accepted) but here I'm more curious about why I have to 're-run' `:set ft=python` for it to trigger.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble yea I have `:filetype on` in my vimrc.

Comment: 1. Always use `augroup`; 2. Do not change global settings from buffer-specific autocommands. Normally that makes no sense, so you should rewrite your example to do something more sensible. 3. Make sure you've read `:h autocmd-nested`

Comment: @Matt thanks for this. What is a "buffer-specific autocommand" ?

Comment: I mean "FileType" event is triggered for each buffer independently (even possibly multiple times per buffer). I don't see how setting global syntax from it could make any sense.